# how to add different class for active menu links

Tags: php, wordpress

my url is :

```
wp/ShowMatch.php?Embed=Soccer&Show=3
```

the php is;

```
        <?php
        $PID = $post->ID;
        $PShow = get_bloginfo('wpurl').'/ShowMatch.php?Embed='; 
        for($i=1;$i<11;$i++){
            if(get_post_meta($PID, 'Poz_Pozembed_'.$i, true)){
            echo '<li class="MoreLinks"><a href="'.$PShow.$PID.'&Show='.$i.'">KANAL '.$i.'</a></li>';
            }
        }           
        ?>
```

If user watch 4.channel the link is going to be like

```
wp/ShowMatch.php?Embed=Soccer&Show=4
```

i want to add some active class for my html output (for li tag.) with jquery .. Is that possible.

Any help thanks.

Comment: $('li.MoreLinks').addClass('MyActiveClass');

Comment: thanks for your comment but , i mean if is active link ;)

Comment: so you mean in your case when ($i == 3)? Then why do you wnat to use jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$PID = $post->ID;
$PShow = get_bloginfo('wpurl').'/ShowMatch.php?Embed=';
$get_i = get_query_var('Show');

for($i=1;$i<11;$i++){
    if(get_post_meta($PID, 'Poz_Pozembed_'.$i, true)){
        echo '<li class="MoreLinks '.($get_i == $i ? 'active' : '').'">'.
                '<a href="'.$PShow.$PID.'&Show='.$i.'">KANAL '.$i.'</a>'.
            '</li>';
    }
}           
?>
```

Comment: Does onlineapplab's edit work? You have to add any query vars that are not WordPress objects to the array of recognised query vars to be able to retrieve it from the $wp_query global. And since when did copying a previously posted  answer become the thing to do?

Answer (score 1):

```
    for($i=1;$i<11;$i++){
        if(get_post_meta($PID, 'Poz_Pozembed_'.$i, true)){
        echo '<li class="MoreLinks'.(isset($_GET['Show']) && $_GET['Show']==$i?' active':'').'">
            <a href="'.$PShow.$PID.'&Show='.$i.'">KANAL '.$i.'</a>
        </li>';
        }
    }
```

Comment: it seems it is wordpress so probably get_query_var() instead of $_GET would be better

Comment: You have to add any query vars that are not WordPress objects to the array of recognised query vars to be able to retrieve it from the $wp_query global. Use $_GET in this instance